# Overloading an operator as a member function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, member-functions

I'm working on a vector class and am trying to overload some operators. I've looked at countless examples, tried every alteration I can think of, and still g++ is complaining

```
include/vector.cpp:9:38: error: no ‘vec vec::operator+(const vec&)’ member function declared in class ‘vec’
```

Obviously g++ is telling me that I'm defining a member function but that I haven't declared my operator as a member function.

Here is the code (I've omitted most of it as it is working fine and is not relevant):
vec.h

```
#ifndef _BEN_VECTOR
#define _BEN_VECTOR

#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
class vec{
public:
    /* Constructor */
    vec(double X, double Y);
    /* OPERATORS */
    vec operator+( const vec& other);

private:
    int dims;
    double x;
    double y;
};
#endif /* _BEN_VECTOR */
```

vec.cpp:

```
#include "vector.h"

/* CONSTRUCTORS */
vec::vec(double X, double Y){
    x = X; y = Y; dims = 2;
}

/* OPERATORS */
vec vec::operator+( const vec& other ){
    vec v(this->gety() + other->getx(), this->gety() + other->gety());
    return v;
}
```

Sorry if this is a duplicate -- I've been scouring the interwebz for hours now and haven't found anything. I'm sure I'll be embarrassed when I see how obvious my mistake is :) Thanks

Comment: Your code looks correct, did you implement `getx()` and `gety()` functions? They don't seem declared/defined. Are you sure that's your only error? I compiled your code successfully, http://ideone.com/FZPkRH

Comment: This code is correct. Is it really the one you have? Maybe you declared the operator `const` (which would actually make sense) but the definition is non-`const`.

Comment: This is copied and pasted -- I got rid of just about everything else. getx(), gety() are working properly - i've been using them all day.

Comment: @BenKushigian 2 things to try: 1. Name your header with something other than `vector.h`. Even though you use `#include "vector.h"`, sometimes compilers end up including stuff from the standard lib anyway and you might have some kind of file/name clash. 2. Marking `operator+` as const, as it isn't modifying any members.  `vec operator+( const vec& other) const;` I don't think that's the source of your error, but that might help avoid future ones at least.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Ike -- thanks for the heads up on the naming convention, I'll change it around. As far as the const goes I had tried that (and will probably revert back). I've been trying to simplify the code as much as possible to get spot any mistakes.

Comment: Typo alert: This: `this->gety() + other->getx()` is clearly syntactically wrong, and looks like it's almost certainly logically wrong as well. You probably intended `getx() + other.getx()`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'll take some time to try and recreate the problem on a smaller scale. Sorry, should have checked before hand.

Comment: OK, I figured out what was happening. My editor was saving into a temp file instead of the current file so I was compiling with a file that hadn't been changed in hours! Not sure what to do here - should I delete this thread since it now apropos of nothing? thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is part of my Vector2 class maybe this will help you.

```
class Vector2 {
public:
    union {
        float m_f2[2];
        struct {
            float m_fX;
            float m_fY;
        };
    };

    inline Vector2();
    inline Vector2( float x, float y );
    inline Vector2( float* pfv );

    // ~Vector2(); // Default Okay

    // Operators
    inline Vector2 operator+() const;
    inline Vector2 operator+( const Vector2 &v2 ) const;
    inline Vector2& operator+=( const Vector2 &v2 );

};

inline Vector2::Vector2() : 
m_fX( 0.0f ),
m_fY( 0.0f ) {
}

inline Vector2::Vector2( float x, float y ) :
m_fX( x ),
m_fY( y ) {
}

inline Vector2::Vector2( float* pfv ) :
m_fX( pfv[0] ),
m_fY( pfv[1] ) {
}

// operator+() - Unary
inline Vector2 Vector2::operator+() const {
    return *this; 
}

// operator+() - Binary
inline Vector2 Vector2::operator+( const Vector2 &v2 ) {
    return Vector2( m_fX + v2.m_fX, m_fY + v2.m_fY );
}

// Operator+=()
inline Vector2& Vector2::operator+=( const Vector2 &v2 ) {
    m_fX += v2.m_fX;
    m_fY += v2.m_fY;
    return *this;
}
```